# Test Spring/SpringBoot without Application

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-test

I want to write integration tests that will have to use Spring Framework and a custom JPA provider. Straightforward answer as I thought would be to create a test class and annotate it as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class Test { ...
```

Hoping for the all of the default auto-configuration required to happen on its own. But it doesn't the error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
```

Can I avoid creating the:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApp { ...
```

and only use src/test/java folder and provide configuration with "@SpringBootTest(classes=...)"? What kind of configuration class do I need then?

Comment: @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes={SpringBootApp.class})

Comment: And where do you get SpringBootApp.class from?? @A

Comment: A base configuration is still needed. Either A SpringBootApplication, or a normal `Configuration`. The SpringBootApplication is a meta annotation contains `SpringBootConfiguration`, which is a type of `Configuration`. You can just create a static embedded in the test class and annotate it with `@SpringBootApplication`. Be aware other tests may pick it up.

Comment: Would you be so kind to write an answer? and maybe give more insight on why this is needed, like, what exactly is SpringBootTest annotation is looking for.

Comment: Please show where main class is located. Test should be at the same package

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean, please read the question again

Answer (score 0):

I just got the problem let me go back to begining;
First add a configuration class ApplicationContainer

```
public final class ApplicationContainer {
private static volatile ApplicationContainer singleton;
private ApplicationContext context;
private ApplicationContainer()
{
}

public static ApplicationContainer getInstance()
{
    if(ApplicationContainer.singleton == null)
    {
        synchronized(ApplicationContainer.class)
        {
            if(ApplicationContainer.singleton == null)
            {
                ApplicationContainer.singleton = new ApplicationContainer();
            }
        }
    }
    return ApplicationContainer.singleton;
}

public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

public <T> T getBean(Class<T> requiredType)
{
    if(this.context == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("ApplicationContainer is not started");
    }
    return this.context.getBean(requiredType);
}

public void start()
{
    if(this.context == null)
    {
        this.context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);
    }
}

public void stop()
{
    if(this.context == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(this.context instanceof AnnotationConfigApplicationContext)
    {
        ((AnnotationConfigApplicationContext)this.context).close();
    }
    this.context = null;
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.domain.package")
public static class ApplicationConfig
{
    }}
```

And change your test class's like that:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ApplicationContainer.ApplicationConfig.class})
public class YourTestIT {
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
@Before
public void up() {
    ApplicationContainer.getInstance().setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
}
@After
public void down() {
    ApplicationContainer.getInstance().stop();
}
//test cases
}
```

then you can @Autowired your repository classes and use directly also you should add IT extension your test class name.

Comment: Same Error, java.lang.IllegalStateException

Comment: If you try to connect database on test you can create a application.test.properties and you can configure with that way (you can use h2 for in memory or you can connect another data source)

Comment: I'm testing 3rd party JPA technology

Comment: Then you can not use @DataJpaTest don’t change first annotations and configure application.test.properties

Comment: Is this the simpliest way to do that?

Comment: you need a custom ApplicationContainer in this situation, maybe you can also inject a entity manager for using the db which is you define on application.test.properties or you can directly use db which is defined application.properties you should roll back all transactions on this way.